# How to group NULL field

Tags: mysql, group-by

After this query :

```
SELECT forum_categories.id AS category_id, forum_categories.title, forum_topics.id AS topic_id, forum_topics.title, user
FROM forum_categories JOIN forum_topics ON forum_categories.id=forum_topics.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_views ON forum_topics.id=forum_views.topic_id
WHERE forum_categories.id=6
ORDER BY forum_categories.id
```

I got this results :

[image]

Now, I'd like to :

- add another field in the select, called **thereIsANull**
- group all my results by the field <strike>*user*</strike> **category_id**
- setting **thereIsANull** to 1 if there isn't a NULL in the field user (while grouping), 0 otherwise.

So in the example below, the result must be 1 row :

```
6    Welcome    (some topic_id)     (some title)   (djfonplaz or null)   0
```

and, if all user was different from NULL :

```
6    Welcome    (some topic_id)     (some title)   (djfonplaz)   1
```

How can I do it on MySql?

Comment: If you group on user, what aggregate function do you want to do? Either way, this could help you with setting a value to 1 or 0 depending on if something is NULL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: yes, but I need to group by category_id and set on that variable 1 or 0, not group by user (else it will return 2 different rows).

Comment: you want the field "thereIsANull" to be 0 if any field is null or just user?

Comment: @Adam Ingmansson : thereIsANull should be 1 if every value of the field user is different from NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  forum_categories.id AS category_ids
  , forum_categories.title as titles
  , forum_topics.id AS topic_ids
  , forum_topics.title as topic_titles
  , count(*) as NumberOfRows
  , GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(user,'(no user)')) AS users 
  , (count(*) - count(user)) as IsThereANull  
FROM forum_categories 
INNER JOIN forum_topics ON forum_categories.id=forum_topics.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_views ON forum_topics.id=forum_views.topic_id
WHERE forum_categories.id=6
GROUP BY category_id
ORDER BY forum_categories.id
```

IsThereANull will be `0` is there's no null and 1 or more if there is.

Comment: Yes yoi are right, I wrong explain group by user. In fact I want to group by category_id, and doing it, have a new field (thereIsANull) which check the value of the user...

Comment: Uhm...looks intelligent :) Tonight I'll try and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following query should get the result that you are looking for:

```
SELECT forum_categories.id AS category_id, forum_categories.title, 
       forum_topics.id AS topic_id, forum_topics.title, user, 
       (
          SELECT MAX(IF(COUNT(*), 0, 1))
          FROM forum_categories JOIN forum_topics ON 
               forum_categories.id=forum_topics.category_id
          LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_views ON forum_topics.id=forum_views.topic_id
          WHERE forum_categories.id=6 AND user IS NULL
    ) AS thereIsANull
FROM forum_categories JOIN forum_topics ON forum_categories.id=forum_topics.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_views ON forum_topics.id=forum_views.topic_id
WHERE forum_categories.id=6 AND user IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY forum_categories.id
```

Comment: @markzzz: The only query that I have is that you are setting thereIsANull to 1 if there isn't a NULL - is that correct?

Comment: No it doesnt works! In fact it returns 2 line (because group by NULL and "djfonplaz").

Comment: yes, but it must return only 1 row, with thereIsANull to 1  there isn't a NULL, 0 otherwise

Comment: @markzzz: Sorry, it wasn't clear that you wanted 1 row with an extra field flagging NULL users

Comment: @markzzz: I've updated the SQL to try to get you the result that you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would do as you want:

```
SELECT cat.id AS category_id, 
       cat.title, 
       top.id AS topic_id, 
       top.title, 
       user,
       (
           (
               SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_categories 
               WHERE id = cat.id AND user IS NULL
           ) > 0 -- This is to check wether if any NULL is found
       ) as thereIsANull 
FROM forum_categories as cat
JOIN forum_topics as top ON cat.id = top.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_views as view ON top.id = view.topic_id
WHERE cat.id = 6 -- You can ofcourse change this to whatever variable your using
GROUP BY cat.id -- Just an ordinary group by category id
ORDER BY cat.id
```

Assuming that the field user is found in the forum_categories table, other wise just modify the subquery to join that table where you get the user from

Note that Thiis is basically the same as the one [Cez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263671/cez) wrote, so he deserves some credits to, only difference is the subquery and grouping by category id instead of user.

Try it out and let me know if it was correct :)

Comment: Thanks for try, but to be honest I think the Johan one is the best, what do you think about?

Comment: Yes, its better in terms or preformance and about the same in readability. Only consider that  `NumberOfRows` will be the same as the number of users found per category id, not the actual number of rows. Also `users` will be a list of users found (like `'User1, User2, User3'`) but that's probably a good thing :)

Comment: Uhm? I don't have understand you last message :) Can you give an example? Thanks